# Is there a standard way to include ORCID in TeX / PDF?

Tags: metadata, author, hyperlink

I would like to add the ORCID to the metadata of documents I write. Is this possible with PDF? Is there a standard way to include it in TeX?

The nicest way would be if there way a standard TeX command so that the compiled PDF would automatically have this information. But if it is possible to add this after the PDF was compiled, it would be nice, too.

The simplest way to add the ORCID to the TeX code is adding a comment

```
% ORCID of the author: http://orcid.org/0000-0002-6517-1690
```

But how do other people add their ORCID to papers? Is there a recommendation how to do it, so that scripts / search engines can use the information?

Comment: You can use `hyperref` to set metadata for the generated PDF (e.g., the `pdfauthor` or `pdfcreator` fields), but that's indeed more of a question for TeX.SE. Whether anybody actually extracts that metadata in a structured fashion so that there's any benefit from doing this is a different matter...

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/214622/listing-orcid-in-latex-papers

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, and the mathoverflow question linked by Christian, you can add the ORCiD to your address information. I've now twice had this picked up automatically by Springer as part of the publication process (and then the paper automatically added to my ORCiD record upon publication via CrossRef). I can't speak as to whether this applies to other publishers also.

Comment: Still unsolved… This information also belongs into `XMP` metadata.

Answer (score 38):

Although the previous answers are more than complete, I found out that a simple package `orcidlink` has just been pushed on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink) to fulfill your need!

[image]

Comment: Originated from a question on this site, it seems https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445563/ieeetran-how-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf-with-pdflatex

Answer (score 36):

[Academicons](http://jpswalsh.github.io/academicons/) has TeX package at https://ctan.org/pkg/academicons which is supported by ORCiD. You may also download SVG or PNG icons from ORCiD website, https://orcid.org/trademark-and-id-display-guidelines

Example:

1. Add following in Document SetUp section of tex file. Second line will define ORCiD recommended color for icon.

   ```
   \usepackage{academicons}
   \definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
   ```
2. Add following where you like to add ORCiD icon and URL

   ```
   \item \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{\textcolor{orcidlogocol}{\aiOrcid} \hspace{2mm} orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}
   ```

ORCiD [recommends](https://orcid.org/trademark-and-id-display-guidelines) hex: #A6CE39 for icon color. `\hspace{2mm}` is optional, i.e., to give custom space margin between icon and adjacent text.

Preview:

[image]

You can read documentation at https://github.com/diogo-fernan/academicons for details on other icons.

<strike>One unresolved issue is to change icon color to ORCiD specified green color and keep it still hyperlinked.</strike>

Comment: Turns out (after so many edits!) that my answer is irrelevant to the question asked. Nonetheless, academicons package can be used to keep orcid icon beside author lists and make pdf as seen with many online journals.

Comment: I can't make your example work in LaTeX. Is it possible for you to publish a complete example?

Comment: See example here: https://gist.github.com/sbamin/1d2a8aff986d4e6156771dea0d645c52 and [output.pdf](https://ibb.co/eZj1Q9). I use [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) and lualatex.

Comment: Thank you but in your example the ORCID logo does not come near the author name. That was really my problem.

Comment: `Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"`. It seems limited to `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Comment: @ar2015 you can try: `\def\orcid#1{\kern .08em\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=0.7em]{orcid.png}}}` and then use `\orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}` – download the png from https://figshare.com/articles/ORCID_iD_icon_graphics/5008697

Answer (score 10):

If there are several authors, make a new command with the argument of the ORCID.

Using @Samir's answer, create a XeLaTeX document with the following at the top:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor[HTML]{A6CE39}{\aiOrcid}}}

\title{Some paper}

\author{
  Josiah Carberry \orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097} \and
  Ema Nowlen \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000} \and
  Nella Penfold \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000} \and
  Lorita Barthel \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000} \and
  Sigrid Pardini \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000} \and
  Sherri Sanks \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000} \and
  Maryln Tall \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000} \and
  Dwain Gooslin \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Cool.

\end{document}
```

[image: out]

Comment: Not working properly. Output is as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445563/178369). [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445583/178369) works.

Answer (score 5):

From the linked related answer:  Springer picks up ORCID from LaTeX in the following format:  Add it as the last line of your address. NOTE: this is in the header, but not wrapped by \hypersetup{}

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\author{Herr Doktor John Smith}
\address{Dept. of Mathematical Sciences \\
     University of Awesome\\
     Liverpool 56893-3242\\
     Albion \\ 
     ORCiD: 0000-0004-8882-8330}
\email{profSmithRules@awesome.edu}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide any reference(s) for this?

Comment: The Springer LNCS template now includes a `\orcidID{0000-1111-2222-3333}` command to add after an author name. You can get the latest templates from: [http://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines]

Comment: unfortunately, that only prints the orcid in `[0000-...]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following template of Springer journals with some additions
where I make hyperlink to the image of ORCID in `\author`.

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended,final,numbook,envcountsect,envcountsame,envcountreset]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx} %%%% This is very important with image %%%%%
%
\usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% My Package %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% for hyperlink
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% My Commond %%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% for author affod
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
%\journalname{name}
%
\begin{document}

\title{topology%\thanks{Grants or other notes
%about the article that should go on the front page should be
%placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.}
}
%\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\titlerunning{topology}        % if too long for running head

\author{Ali Al-Obaidi \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0003-4221-7622}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{figures/orcid.jpg}}      \and
        Smath John\href{https://orcid.org/0000-0002-0000-0000}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{figures/orcid.jpg}}}%etc.



\authorrunning{Al-Obaidi and John } % if too long for running head

% The correct dates will be entered by the editor


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

%\keywords{ccccc \and cccc \and cccccc  \and xxxxn \and xxxxx \and xxxxx}
% \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
%\subclass{AAA \and AAA \and AAAA \and AAA\and aaaa}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to download this Color icon (The best choice is iD icon 16x16) from this link
https://orcid.org/trademark-and-id-display-guidelines

Comment: It's not working. When I download the pdf version of it, the image remain just as an image, not a hyperlink which will direct me to my orcid profile.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to use the SVG package:

```latex
\usepackage{svg}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\includesvg[width=10pt]{orcid}}}
```

Download the SVG logo from the ORCID website: [orcid.svg](https://orcid.org/assets/vectors/orcid.logo.icon.svg)

Then (like previous answers) simply do:

```latex
\author{John Doe \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
```

Answer (score 3):

For overleaf is no so trivial to use academia icons. Therefore my solution was to do:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% Make Orcid icon
\definecolor{lime}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\orcidicon}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lime, fill=lime] (0,0) 
    circle [radius=0.16] 
    node[white] {{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \tiny ID}};
    \draw[white, fill=white] (-0.0625,0.095) 
    circle [radius=0.007];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{-2mm}
}

\foreach \x in {A, ..., Z}{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname orcid\x\endcsname{\noexpand\href{https://orcid.org/\csname orcidauthor\x\endcsname}{\noexpand\orcidicon}}
}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor[HTML]{A6CE39}{\orcidicon}}}
```

And then add the icons as `\orcid{0000-0002-2139-514X}`

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution without any additional package required:

```
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\includegraphics[width=8pt]{orcid.png}}}
```

with [orcid.png](https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/8439044/preview/8439044/preview.jpg) in the 128x128 pixel size and in color.

[image]

Then use

```
\author{Max Mustermann \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
```

to add the ORCID ID after your name.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @divenex you have to download the orcid.png image and put it in the correct directory so LaTeX can find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it even with pdfLaTeX, you just have to draw the icon by yourself in `tikz`, as posted [here for a general number of authors](https://gugushvili.github.io/blog/2019/08/09/orcid) or below for just one or two specific authors (as I would use it). So far for templates like MNRAS or A&A, where LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX (which are needed for `academicons`) are not working properly or are discouraged, this approach works the best.

```
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,hyperref}

% Make Orcid icon
\definecolor{lime}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\orcidicon}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lime, fill=lime] (0,0) 
    circle [radius=0.16] 
    node[white] {{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \tiny ID}};
    \draw[white, fill=white] (-0.0625,0.095) 
    circle [radius=0.007];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{-2mm}
}

% Make commands for any number of authors here.
\newcommand{\orcidJonDoe}{\href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{\orcidicon}}
\newcommand{\orcidJaneDoe}{\href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0001}{\orcidicon}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly acknowledge the work of all Samir, Sebastian Höffner, Mike T, Nagabhushan S N, בנימן הגלילי, Neil P, Ali Al-Obaidi, @Robin Keskisarkka, Václav Pavlík, Agustin Barrachina and ProjectPhysX for their efforts.

The package to be used here is  `orcidlink`.

To use this package, in the preamble include
`\usepackage{orcidlink}`.

Full command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pdfstartview=XYZ,
bookmarks=true,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
pdftex,
bookmarks=true,
linktocpage=true, % makes the page number as hyperlink in table of content
hyperindex=true
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{orcidlink}

\begin{document}

\title{Here is the title}
    
\author{Author 1\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0000}     
    \and
    Author 2\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0000}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the point of all those @'s in your post? They work in comments and in chats, not it posts.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is with the package `fontawesome5`. Import the following packages:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
```

Define the orcid color, roughly given by the following RGB code:

```
\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{rgb}{0.65, 0.807, 0.223}
```

Define a command for displaying the orcid logo and hyperlink:

```
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{$\,$\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor{orcidlogocol}{\faOrcid}}}
```

Then write the orcid logo just as `\orcid{0000-0002-6517-1690}`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, at least when I'm using it on Overleaf, and placing the orcid logo next to my name at the head of the CV

```
\usepackage{orcidlink}
\begin{document}
\makeheading{\scshape{my name}\orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-000X}}
```

Comment: Solutions using the package `orcidlink` were already given in the answers by circuitbreaker and Ahmed Aafaq.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @dexteritas. However, I thought it would also be useful just to point out how to include it in a CV on Overleaf specifically, at least for any newbies like me who happen to stumble on this discussion