# Including Orcid in plain latex using authblk

Tags: author, metadata, authblk

Lets say I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Some paper}

\author[1]{First Last}
\author[2]{Second Last}

\affil[1]{First Affil}
\affil[2]{Second Affil}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

and I want to include the [ORCID](https://orcid.org/) of one of the authors. I would like the symbol with an attached hyperlink appearing after one of the authors' names.

How would I go about this?

Note: This may seem like a duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275578/is-there-a-standard-way-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf) question, in which the following approaches are suggested:

1. Use [Academicons](http://jpswalsh.github.io/academicons/):

   ```
   \usepackage{academicons}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}

   \newcommand{\orcid}[1]{
     \href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor{orcidlogocol}{\aiOrcid}}
   }
   ```

   This works, but only using xelatex and not plain (pdf)latex.
2. Using a suitable graphic (say `orcid.pdf`, converted from one of the [svgs](https://figshare.com/articles/ORCID_iD_icon_graphics/5008697) available:

   ```
   \usepackage{graphicx}

   \newcommand{\orcid}[1]{
     \href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{orcid}}
   }
   ```

   Note that there is a more sophisticated version which scales 
     the icon to the height of the surrounding text using the `scalerel`
     package:

   ```
     \newcommand\orcidicon[1]{
       \href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\mbox{\scalerel{\includegraphics{orcid}}{|}}}}
   ```

   This unfortunately gives me the error

   ```
     ! Use of \\author doesn't match its definition.
   ```

Thus, both of the approaches don't really seem to work for me. Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: The Academicons variant worked well for me, but I had to adjust the spacing around the ORCID Logo a little bit - maybe that is useful for someone else visiting this post:

\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{
  \href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor{orcidlogocol}{\kern -0.4em \aiOrcid \kern -0.4em}}
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy way to set something to a good height relative to the current font is to use dimensions with units of `ex`, which is nominally the height of the lower case `x` in the font.  So naively one would write

```
 \includegraphics[height=1.7ex]{orcid}
```

to include the image.

Unfortunately the `authblk` constructions need the above command to expand nicely; but it doesn't, even after adding `\protect`ion type mechanisms such as `\newrobustcmd` from `etoolbox` (try

```
\newrobustcmd{\orcid}[1]{%
  \href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\includegraphics[height=1.7ex]{orcid}%
  \,#1}}
```

and you will see a very strange effect).

A way round this is to store the graphic appropriately scaled in a box and then use that box in the affiliation.

The combination

```
\newbox{\myorcidaffilbox}
\sbox{\myorcidaffilbox}{\large\includegraphics[height=1.7ex]{orcid}}
```

sets up a box for this purpose and stores the graphic in it; the size `\large` is the font size that is used for printing affiliations.  Then we can write a command

```
\newcommand{\orcidaffil}[1]{%
  \href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\usebox{\myorcidaffilbox}\,#1}}
```

that puts this box in to our orcid construct via a `\usebox` command.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newbox{\myorcidaffilbox}
\sbox{\myorcidaffilbox}{\large\includegraphics[height=1.7ex]{orcid}}
\newcommand{\orcidaffil}[1]{%
  \href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\usebox{\myorcidaffilbox}\,#1}}

\begin{document}

\title{Some paper}

\author[1]{First Last}
\author[2]{Second Last}

\affil[1]{First Affil \orcidaffil{0000-0002-1825-0097}}
\affil[2]{Second Affil}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [orcidlink](https://ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink) package (in version 1.0.4, 1.0.2 is not "robust" enough) is another option:

```
\author[1]{First Last\,\orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0000}\,}
\author[2]{Second Last\,\orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0000}\,}
```

[image: rendered example]