# How to add Orcid ID in LaTex article?

Tags: article

I want to add Orcid ID in Latex article. I have tried several methods that are used for other documentclasses, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide more details: Which document class do you use, and where do you want to add the Orcid Id?

Comment: @gernot Thank you! I use article class. I want to add it to next to the author name.

Comment: If you want to have the id visible in the document, you could just use `\thanks`: `\author{The Name\thanks{OrcID: 0000-0000-0000-0000}}`. Otherwise see e.g. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275578/is-there-a-standard-way-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275578/110998)

Comment: @Mico Well, the answer is linked in my answer, as well as the package that resulted from it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a very up-to-date TeX installation, you can use the `orcidlink` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{orcidlink}
\begin{document}
\orcidlink{https://orcid.org} is an ORCID link.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise you can use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445583/34063), which it is based on.

Comment: The first method does not compile in my Overleaf account. The second method I tried previously, but it didn't run correctly. Maybe I should try again.

Comment: @tyMind Unfortunately, Overleaf is the very opposite of an up-to-date TeX installation. As I do not know what the second method is I can't say much.

Comment: @tyMind Overleaf currently runs TeX Live 2020 but for stability and continuity reasons, doesn't update packages between TeX Live releases. The solution is to fetch the `orcidlink.sty` file from the maintainer's GitHub repository, place it in your project Overleaf project's folder, and then your document should process with no trouble.

Comment: @tyMind The GitHub repository is linked in the comments under the answer that I linked to.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the method written in that Github link, but I got errors. When I write this: \author{Wow wow\, \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0000} } I got an error message, which says:  Use of \\author doesn't match its definition.

Comment: @tyMind I cannot reproduce this error. (This whole thread is also a very interesting sociology experiment. The link I added to the answer got meanwhile shared by no less than three other users. Rather than reading what other say it is much better to just repeat things. And then your error without any document or context...)