# How to show ORCID ID with a centered icon?

Tags: superscripts, hyperlink, icon

From [How to add Orcid ID in LaTex article?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572730/201615), they suggest to display the ORCID icon with the following package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{orcidlink}
\begin{document}
\orcidlink{https://orcid.org} is an ORCID link.
\end{document}
```

However when I do this, the ORCID icon is shown as a *superscript* (the letters `ID` are above the letters of the rest of the sentence):

[image]

**How can I show it centered as in the following image (the letters `ID` start on the same height as the letters of the rest of the sentence)?**

[image]

Comment: How are you compiling your code? I get a centred link https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYjL9.png

Comment: Did you try with a different viewer?

Comment: I'm doing it on overleaf.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for me your image is still not centered as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572731/201615

Comment: @Puco4 Download the pdf from overleaf and view it with a different viewer.

Comment: @Puco4 is your complaint about the positioning and size of the hyperlink, or the graphic itself? The result you are getting from compilation appears consistent with the examples given in https://info.orcid.org/brand-guidelines/

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I do it and I see it like the image in your link, but if you notice it is differently positioned from the second image where the letters inside the icon are on the same height as the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @DaiBowen I would like to see the letters inside the icon (ID) on the same height as the normal font (as displayed in the second image I show).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `orcidlink` package scales the height of the icon so it matches an uppercase X (which is a very sensible choice) if you want to change the size of the icon, you can either redeclare the scaling factors given in the code of `orcidlink` (especially `\@curXheight`) or make your own, using ?academicons`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{orcid-green}   {RGB} {166, 206, 57}

\DeclareRobustCommand\orcidlink[1]{%
  \texorpdfstring{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor{orcid-green}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{\scalebox{1.1}{\aiOrcid}}}}}{https://orcid.org/#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\orcidlink{0000-0001-7559-9597} is an ORCID link.
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to play a little with the scaling factors of `\raisebox` and `\scalebox` until it meets your expectations...

Comment: @Puco4 - `academicons` requires Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX