# How to add ORCID ID icon for Springer \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} format?

Tags: author, author-number, sv-classes

It seems like adding ORCID ID ICON to Springer \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} format is different from IEEE format. I tried several methods but I could not solve it. Can someone help me with the following code and show how can I add ORCID ID ICON next to the Author's names?  Here is my MWE:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
    %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
    %%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
    %%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
    %%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
    %%EndComments
    gsave
    newpath
    20 20 moveto
    20 220 lineto
    220 220 lineto
    220 20 lineto
    closepath
    2 setlinewidth
    gsave
    .4 setgray fill
    grestore
    stroke
    grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if availab

% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%burada itibaren ekledim%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{→}{$\to$}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrtime}
% fnpct instead of footmisc:
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}

% patch \maketitle:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\usepackage[misc,geometry]{ifsym} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    

    
    \title{Title of the Article}
    
    
    
    
    \author{%
        Author 1 Name Surname \protect\affmark[1, 2] \and Author 2 Name Surname\affmark[1] 
    }
    \authorrunning{Esra Yeniaras \and Murat Cenk}
    %\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head
    
    \institute{ 
        \Letter  $ ~~~$Author 1 Name Surname \\
        $~~~~~~~~$author2@..edu  \\ \\      %  \\
        %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
        %\and
        $~~~~~~~$   Author 2 Name Surname \at
        $~~~~~~~$   author1@..edu\\ \\
        $~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[1]  Institution 1, Colorado,USA}\\ \\
        $~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[2]  Instituton 2 , Ontario, CANADA}\\
        %\affaddr{\LaTeX\ University}%
    }
    \date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
    % The correct dates will be entered by the editor
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \lipsum     
            \keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3 bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3  \and bla3.bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3} 
        \end{abstract}
    
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \label{intro}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this question is about how to add the ORCID icon when using the svjour3 style, then the answer should be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275578/164146).

However, if the goal is to have your ORCID iD show up in a publication with Springer Nature (and thus using svjour3), then the answer is: the journal will add it for you, if you provided your ORCID iD during the submission process ([source](https://www.springernature.com/gp/researchers/orcid)).

If anyone knows why svjour3 does not provide an \orcidID command, I'd be interested to know. It seems to me that this would be easier and less confusing.