# Including ORCID ID in article class elsarticle.cls

Tags: symbols, elsarticle, hyperlink

I'm writing an article in elsarticle class on Overleaf.

We want to create ORCID ID's in the author information because the university dictates it even for submissions.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title Goes Here}

\author[add1]{My Name Is} [orcid=0000-0000-XXXX-XXXX]
\author[add2]{Your Name Is}[orcid=0000-0000-XXXX-XXXX]

\address[add1]{Department of Bla Bla}
\address[add2]{Department of Gra Gra}

\begin{abstract}
It goes here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Key \sep Words 
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

Some pages here.

\end{document}
```

These answers didn't work:

[Is there a standard way to include ORCID in TeX / PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275578/is-there-a-standard-way-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf)

[IEEEtran - How to include ORCID in TeX/PDF with PdfLatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445563/ieeetran-how-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf-with-pdflatex/445583#445583)

How do I create link for ORCID?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [orcidlink](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink) package?

Comment: No, I wasn't. I'll try that.

Comment: Does it work on Overleaf? I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Sorry, but a statement such as "I couldn't make it work" is simply not actionable. If you expect to receive useful advice on this site, you yourself need to provide useful information about what exactly you tried and what exactly claims such as "couldn't make it work" and "these answers didn't work" entail. For instance, did you receive warning and or error messages? If so, what did they say?

Comment: I had `orcidlink` package working on the IEEE format. When migrating to the elsevier format I could not get it to work properly. They way I had, the `orcidlink` icon was also suplicated at the footnote for email.