# َAdding the link of a web site

Tags: links

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

    \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage{sectsty}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

    \frenchspacing
    \sectionfont{%
      \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
      \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \bigskip

    \begin{flushleft}

    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \fontfamily{phv}\large
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      \Huge\bfseries Name Name \\[1ex]
      Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)
      \end{tabular}%
    }
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
    \end{tabular}

    \end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

I want to add a link to my ORCID account

[image]

like the following

[image]

Comment: Did you see the postings [Is there a standard way to include ORCID in TeX / PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275578/5001) and [IEEEtran - How to include ORCID in TeX/PDF with PdfLatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445563/5001), and are you familiar with the package called [orcidlink](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/orcidlink)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like so? I'm using a `tikz` environment to create the circled text and by changing the `hyperref` parameters to make the link look white, you can also leave the `hyperref` parameters clean and modify the text in the `tikz` implementation of the circled node

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=white,urlcolor=white]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt, fill=green, draw=green] (char) {\small #1};}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frenchspacing
\sectionfont{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bigskip

\begin{flushleft}

\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\large
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \Huge\bfseries Name Name $^{\text{\circled{\href{http://www.overleaf.com}{ID}}}}$ \\[1ex]
  Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)
  \end{tabular}%
}
\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\end{tabular}

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just I hope that the color of the circle is like the pic

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @Student: The colour is RGB = (166, 206, 57) or Hex = `#A6CE39`.

Comment: @Werner What should I change in the answer? Thanks a lot

Comment: @MiguelFernandoRangelMartnez I mean that I want to change the color as my pic. Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, you can use the `xcolor` environment to generate a new color and use it in the fill and draw parameter in the tikz node.

Comment: @MiguelFernandoRangelMartnez I hope that you edit your answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please see my related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628232/changing-a-color-of-a-link/628234?noredirect=1#comment1566894_628234  ?