# Changing a color of a link

Tags: color

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.60}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}   %
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=white,urlcolor=white]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=citeblue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt, fill=green, draw=green] (char) {\small #1};}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frenchspacing
\sectionfont{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bigskip

\begin{flushleft}

\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\large
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \Huge\bfseries Name Name $^{\text{\circled{\href{http://www.overleaf.com}{ID}}}}$ \\[1ex]
  Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)
  \end{tabular}%
}
\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\end{tabular}

\end{flushleft}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{p1}\href{http://www.overleaf.com}{{Author,} {paper,}  Linear Algebra Appl. }
    
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I want to change this color

[image]

Like the following

[image]

Comment: You have to change the `fill` and `draw` colors in the `\circled` command definition. There you see the `green` color. To change you have to discover the color you wish, maybe in RGB values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about `fontawesome5`'s `\faOrcid` icon?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.60}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}   %
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=white,urlcolor=white]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=citeblue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}

\frenchspacing
\sectionfont{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bigskip

\begin{flushleft}

\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\large
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \Huge\bfseries Name Name \href{http://www.overleaf.com}{\textsuperscript{\color[RGB]{166,206,57}\faOrcid}} \\[1ex]
  Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)
  \end{tabular}%
}
\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\end{tabular}

\end{flushleft}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{p1}\href{http://www.overleaf.com}{{Author,} {paper,}  Linear Algebra Appl. }
    
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Professor. But it does not compile

Comment: I think there is a problem in your code since you deleted the pic

Comment: @Student: On my system, the code compiles just fine and results in the output I included in my answer. Do you get an error message upon trying to compile the example and if so, which?

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...nt \color [RGB]{166,206,57}\faOrcid 
                                                  
l.41     }
          
?

Comment: @Student: Does a more minimal version of the code, one that produces just the logo, compile properly? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\color[RGB]{166,206,57}\faOrcid 
\end{document}`